# as.POSIXCt returning incorrect date value in R

Tags: r

I am trying to convert the Eopch time interval using as.POSIXct function in R
into the local timezone and in the Europe/Vienna timezone. But for both the timezone its displaying a weird date

```
as.POSIXct(1385856600000, origin = "1970-01-01", tz='CET')
[1] "45886-01-17 23:40:00 CET"
> as.POSIXct(1385856600000, origin = "1970-01-01")
[1] "45886-01-18 04:10:00 IST"
```

What i am typing wrong here ?

Comment: It seems like you have milliseconds there. Divide by 1000.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `anytime` package too.. much simpler to use than as.POSIXCt

```
anytime(1385856600000/1000)
[1] "2013-12-01 05:40:00 IST"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your time is in milliseconds. If you divide by 1000, you get:

```
as.POSIXct(1385856600, origin = "1970-01-01")
[1] "2013-12-01 05:40:00 IST"
```